# Google vision api text detection

Tags: text, detection, vision

I am using google vision api to recognise  text from image. The image in Japanese language.

But response is not in Japanese language it is in English. Can any body tell me how to change english to Japanese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a language hint in the AnnotateImageRequest.  For example, in C#:

```
       var responses = vision.Images.Annotate(
            new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest()
            {
                Requests = new[] {
                new AnnotateImageRequest() {
                    Features = new [] { new Feature() { Type =
                      "TEXT_DETECTION"}},
                    Image = new Image() { Content = imageContent },
                    ImageContext = new ImageContext()
                    {
                        LanguageHints = new string[] { "ja" }
                    }
                }
           }
            }).Execute();
```

Comment: @{@"requests":@[
                @{@"image":
                      @{@"content":imageData},
                 
                  
                  @"imageContext":
                      @{@"languageHints":@[@"ja"]},
                  
                
                  
                  @"features":@[
                @{@"type":@"TEXT_DETECTION",
                  @"maxResults":@16},
            
                    ]
                  
                  
                  }]};

Comment: SIR, IS THIS OK FOR OBJETIVE-C

Comment: I don't know Objective-C well enough to answer.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try Type "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION" instead of "TEXT_DETECTION",
For example (in Java),

```
Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION).build();
```